# Exchange Web Services SMTP address error : ErrorNonExistentMailbox

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Please i use a service windows to acced to my email. i have this exception when i try to bind my folder
Here is my code

```
private static readonly ExchangeVersion _ExchangeServerVersion = ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010;
            private static readonly IWebProxy _ExchangeWebProxy;

    public static EmailClient CreateClient(string account, string password, string domain, string mailtowatch=null ,TimeSpan? timeout = null )
    {
        if (!timeout.HasValue)
        {
            timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        }
        EmailClient result = new EmailClient();
        result.Mailbox = mailtowatch;
        ExchangeService client = new ExchangeService(_ExchangeServerVersion);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            client.Credentials = new WebCredentials(account, password, domain);
        }
        try
        {
            client.AutodiscoverUrl(mailtowatch);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            client.Url = new Uri("https://office.natixis.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        }
        client.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, mailtowatch);

        client.WebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        client.WebProxy = _ExchangeWebProxy;
        result.Service = client;
        client.Timeout = (int)(timeout.Value.TotalMilliseconds);
        return result;
    }
*******************************
and i call it here 
*******************************
Folder folder = null;
FolderId id = null;
if (criteria.FolderName != null)
{
    log.Debug(string.Format("Getting folder {0}", criteria.FolderName));
    id = GetFolderId(criteria.FolderName);
}
log.Debug("Start binding folder");
if (criteria.Password == null)
{

    var folderTemp = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, criteria.EmailToWatch); //Or the folder you want to search in
    folder = Folder.Bind(Service, folderTemp);
}
else
{
    //client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    folder = Folder.Bind(Service, id ?? new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox( criteria.EmailToWatch)  )); 

}
```

but on bindid the folder i have an exception ErrorNonExistentMailbox.
Even when i use UseDefaultCredentials = true is not working

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question? and/or the inner exception

Comment: i have no more information on InnerException, it equal to Null.
only i have that message The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it. And ErrorCode = ErrorNonExistentMailbox

Comment: Have you tried this? [support.microsoft resolution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/3006861/-the-smtp-address-has-no-mailbox-associated-with-it-error-when-you-acc)

Comment: No, i didn't because im working on difrents Environement, now it not working on Rec Env, but i don't know for Prex and Prod. 
for information when i launch with my visual studio it work fine only en server

Comment: please some one can help,

Comment: The error message is too broad. If you Google the error "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it", multiple possible solutions are returned. Id advise you to try the different solutions and if they all fail then ask a new question, containing as much details as possible. This article might help https://www.codetwo.com/kb/error-errornonexistentmailbox/